# Retrieve the struct from array of structs when struct field of struct type matches with specific value in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
Schema

root
|-- promotion-id: string (nullable = true)
|-- custom-attributes: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- custom-attribute: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- attribute-id: string (nullable = true)


Sample Input Data 

promotion-id    custom-attributes.custom-attribute
100             [["x",1000],["y",2000]]
200             [["x",3000],["z",4000]]

Sample Output

promotion-id    col X   col Y   col Z
100             1000    2000    null
200             3000    null    4000
```

Am using spark 2.3 and I have a dataframe with the below schema

If you notice custom-attributes.custom-attribute is an array(struct)

Now I have the attribute ID as "x". I need to check if attribute ID "x" exists in any of the struct inside the array and get the value output.

I have a list of attribute ID's and the column names

say - if I have an attribute ID as "x" get the value of it and populate in col X

Below is the attribute ID to column mapping
x -> col X , y -> col Y , z -> col Z

If there is no attribute available in the struct then just put as null in that column

Answer (score 0):

You can `inline` the array of structs and do a pivot on the value.

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "*", 
    "inline(`custom-attributes`.`custom-attribute`)"
).groupBy("promotion-id").pivot("value").agg(first(col("attribute-id")))

df2.show
+------------+----+----+----+
|promotion-id|   x|   y|   z|
+------------+----+----+----+
|         100|1000|2000|null|
|         200|3000|null|4000|
+------------+----+----+----+
```

Note the use of backticks to escape the hyphens in the column names. In general, it is not a good practice to use hyphens in column names because they could also mean subtraction of columns.

Comment: Thank you ! can we use multiple columns in pivot ? Say for col X, pick struct field 2 if not empty else pick struct field 3